# Generated java code formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, stringtemplate

I am generating Java Code from  my Domain specific Language (DSL). My Language is using String Template files for generating Java Code from DSL.

My problem  is that String Template files generate un-formatted Java code in Eclipse. Whenever I generated code, I have to  press cntr + Shift + F to format each generated Java file.

Is there any way of generating  formatted code ? I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Why do you want your generated code to be formatted? Do you edit the generated source? Is it so badly formatted that it is not usable? (I imagine that source consisting of one long source line is useless in exception stack traces.)

Comment: I agree with Christin Semrau.  Generated code is like byte code - it does not need to be pretty - or human readable.  Use `\r\n` as your white code character and your stack trace table will be more usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of indentation in your `StringTemplate` templates. I tend to write templates for fragments of code such as a function definitions, function calls or even argument declarations that have to be expanded over a collection of variable elements, and combined them programmatically as arguments to a single souce file template.

Answer (score 2):

At least you can select `the project`/`the package` of your interest and use the `Ctrl+Shift+F` shortcut to format all of them immediately. This is much better compare to formatting each and every files.